# PHPUnit shows weird characters as output?

Tags: phpunit

When I run PHPUnit in Windows on WAMP, I sometimes get weird output like this:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from D:\MrDWorkspace\Zend\mrdelivery\phpunit.xml
←[41;37mF←[0m.... <-------- this is the weird output
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are color codes for screen displays. If you are using a simple DOS window, these do not work, and may be turned off from the command line (omit the --colors option).  Command Line parameters may be found in the [PHPUnit Manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html).

It is possible to run a 'smarter' shell in Windows (PowerShell or something) which will then show the colors properly.

Comment: I was having the same issue and I tried re-running in powershell, but still it's outputting the same weird characters.

Comment: True, I did not get them with Powershell either. However, Cygwin's shell, or even the GIT Bash shell on Windows will display the ANSI colors.  Also, I believe the ANSICON referenced in other answers will work as well.  I disabled the colors, but now that I run the GIT Bash shell for working with GitHub and BitBucket, I have them reenabled in that environment.  Again, the setting may be configured for the command line switch (instead of the configuration XML) and test the shell before calling PHPUnit.

Comment: I just can't seem to get the color coding working correctly. I've tried installing ansicon but it's crashing each time. I tried on gitbash as well, but it's giving me the same weird errors. Just seems like it's not playing well in my windows 8 environment. I've just set colors="false" to avoid it for now.

Comment: I have Windows 7. Colors did work in bash shell.

Comment: I was able to get this working. I had bitdefender running which was quarantining one of the ansicon files, causing the color coding to not work. I got it working in Shell on Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [ANSICON](http://adoxa.hostmyway.net/ansicon/)

1. Download the ANSICON.
2. Extract the files to c:\ansicon\ (For
   example).
3. Go to ANSICON folder using "cd c:\ansicon" on the console
   (cmd), and then type “ansicon -i” without the quotes.
4. Add "c:\ansicon" to your path environment variable.
5. Enjoy!

Note: Windows 32 bits = x86 folder, and Windows 64 bits = x64 folder.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work on my windows 8 environment, but each time I tpe aniscon -i, it doesn't seem to do anything. I try and re-run phpunt after and it just crashes. To resolve this issue I have to re-execute aniscon -u, and things are back working again. Possibly a windows 8 bug